# Visual studio possibly erroneous compiler error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I had to re-image my laptop recently, and reinstalled visual studio (Tried 2018 but it annoyed me, so i rolled back to 2015 which seems to work a lot better)
I opened up an old project, and at first it said failed to find build toolset, so i re-targeted it to the one i had just installed. And tried again to compile, and it failed telling me that in the following function:

```
string getinvnum(vstring range) {
int inv;
string ret;
for (int i = 0; i < range.size(); i++) {
    int temp = stoi(range[i]);
    if (temp > inv) {
        inv = temp;
    }
}
return to_string(inv);}
```

that `cpp(266): error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'inv' used.` and defiantly refuses to compile.

Line 266 is relating to the if statement there.
This is not a complex function at all, and it most surely is initialized, in fact if i hover my mouse over "inv" intellisense picks up it's deceleration.

I then decided to copy and paste my source code into a new project as this error just made no sense to me, commented out code relating to other included project files, and tried to recompile, and it worked without any complaints.

Is there something wrong with this code, or some issue with the change in toolset? 
While everything is working, i'd just like to understand, if possible what happened/what i did which caused this error.

Can anyone explain to me why visual studio is doing this to me?

Edit: Just copied across the whole solution into a new project, and the entire thing now builds without any issues. However the original, while identical code, still tells me this same error.

Comment: "and it most surely is initialized"    `if (temp > inv) {`  not for this line it isn't.  As a general rule ... your compiler is right; when it errors / warns, start with assuming you've done something wrong

Comment: Declared doesn't mean initialized.

Comment: Then why if i copy the entire thing into a new project does it work without issue? Either it's an error or it's not. Is what i am asking.

Comment: `C4700` is normally a warning. In this project, you have "treat warnings as errors" option turned on; in the other project, you have it off. Regarless, `inv` is not in fact initialized, and your program would exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: "works without issues" Undefined behavior is like that, it hides in the shadows and then one day stops working due to a totally unrelated change.  Your memory layout changed.  Garbage left on the stack changed.  The reason your new project doesn't generate the diagnostic is because the new project's settings have the warning turned off.

Comment: Ah, this makes a lot more sense. Thank you all of you. I just wished to understand and learn from my mistake/poor code quality as i just learned so that i can not do it again :) I will accept below answer in 4 mins when i can as this explained it well.

Comment: Whose deceleration does Intellisense pick up again?

Comment: What "annoyed you" about VS 2017 exactly (there is no VS 2018)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inv` is not initialised. Depending on project compiler settings, the compiler version and whether you are using debug or release the compiler may or may not detect this.

To fix the issue simply initialise `inv` to have an initial value. The compiler is trying to protect you against difficult to find bugs due to `inv` having some random value (which may work sometimes as that random value may be 0).

Comment: C4700 is a warning, but if you have ``/WX`` or ``TreatWarningsAsErrors`` turned on, it would be promoted to an error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's an error - a logical error at least - as others have pointed out.  You should not ignore compiler warnings, you should fix them.  MSVC will always warn you about this (and other things) unless you explicitly turn warnings off so be on the lookout in future and pay due attention.  Whether you should tell the compiler to treat warnings as errors is another matter.  I don't.  Opinions vary.

But I have a more specific reason for posting this answer.  In DEBUG builds, The Visual Studio debugger will alert you (with a popup) at runtime if you use an uninitialised variable and show you exactly where you did so.  So, **always** run your code under the debugger and then you will be alerted to mistakes like this, even if you miss the compiler warning.